# Scientific notation for a list of integers in python

Tags: python

I have a list of integers that I'm using as labels on a graph and I need to represent them in scientific notation. Most of the other questions I see pertain to float values, when the number is like 23.16274586938 but my numbers range from 2600000000 to 2900000000 and need to represent them as 2.61e^8 or whatever for the values. I've tried using Decimal, {.2E} and neither of them worked for me. The list has about 50k values in it, with about 12 digits per value.

The solutions I've found online only work when you have one single value. Not when iterating over a list.

my list looks like

x = [5160000000000,63720000000000,326723000000000,3400000000000,...] for 50k values

```
"{:.2e}".format(arr_of_frequencies[i])
```

Using this, where arr_of_frequencies is my list, or some variations of this give me the error

```
IndexError: cannot fit 'int' into an index-sized integer
```

Comment: This is going to depend on which graphing library you are using (which you haven't told us).

Comment: Chart JS for graphing, Flask for taking input

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `str.format()` to print a number in scientific notation.

Use `str.format()` on a number with ""{:e}" as str to format the number in scientific notation.

[image: 1]

To only include a certain number of digits after the decimal point, use "{:.Ne}", where N is the desired number of digits.

[image: 2]

You can further read about formatting [here](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-print-a-number-in-scientific-notation-in-python).

For instance:

```
>>> "{:e}".format(1234566723425254342)
>>> '1.234567e+18'
```

---

```
>>> "{:.4e}".format(123456672342525434234232)
>>> '1.2346e+23'
```

For a very big list you can try generators to do transformation with lazy evaluation:

```
>>> data = open("data.txt", 'r').read()
>>> def reverse(data):
...     for index in range(len(data)):
...             yield "{e}".format(data[index])
...
>>>
>>> for x in reverse(data):
...     print(x)

3.400000e+12
5.160000e+12
6.372000e+13
3.267230e+14
3.400000e+12
5.160000e+12
6.372000e+13
5.160000e+12
6.372000e+13
3.267230e+14
3.400000e+12
5.160000e+12
6.372000e+13
3.267230e+14
3.400000e+12
5.160000e+12
5.160000e+12
6.372000e+13
3.267230e+14
3.400000e+12
5.160000e+12
6.372000e+13
5.160000e+12
6.372000e+13
3.267230e+14
3.400000e+12
5.160000e+12
6.372000e+13
3.267230e+14
3.400000e+12
5.160000e+12
6.372000e+13
.......50000 entries worked
```

Comment: Good. Can you please provide code as text, and not as an image?

Comment: I've tried this and the error it gives me is "IndexError: cannot fit 'int' into an index-sized integer"

Comment: I tried with number of more than 20 digits and it's working, Which version of python are you using

Comment: @trincot, thanks for the suggestion. I have added an example as text for better understanding and easiness

Comment: That works when you know what the value is. Or can put in a single variable, but does not work when you try to iterate over a list for it

Comment: can you share an example

Comment: I think I got you. Python internal memory is not able to handle that many big numbers. I would suggest to have those numbers written in a file and read that file line by line and execute the above command

Comment: I updated to show what my list looks like. Writing and reading 50,000 values to a local file just to format them seems very backwards and unneeded. Doing that would also slow down my program a lot

Comment: Let me try for an alternative solution

Comment: I tried lazy evaluation (using generators) and it worked for me . ( I took data size of 5000) . Can you please try it and let me know if this works for you . I am adding it in the answer

Comment: I just tried for almost 68k records with 20 digits number, it works like charm :)